# Sum of time difference between multiple Mysql rows with changing filters

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a hard time finding a proper SQL query that make a sum of the time difference between multiple rows depending on user filters set on a form written mainly in php.

The structure is:

```
date        time        number  action
2011-08-09  09:11:16    12      S
2014-08-09  09:12:21    12      T
2014-08-09  09:16:59    12      S
2014-08-09  09:17:16    12      T
2014-08-09  09:17:28    12      S
2014-08-09  09:17:44    12      G
2014-08-09  09:21:30    12      T
2014-08-09  09:21:42    12      S
2014-08-09  09:36:08    12      S
2014-08-09  09:37:08    12      B
2014-08-09  09:38:19    12      T
2014-08-09  09:39:53    12      A
2014-08-09  09:42:05    12      S
```

The database is Mysql, approximately 8000 rows are inserted per day, there is almost 1,500,000 rows currently. Users needs to find the sum of time between some specific rows, for exemple the sum of time between rows where action A = S, and action B = T. In that specific case there would be time difference from 4 rows that would needs to be added. Users can make filters on each columns.

Anybody has an idea of the syntax to use in order to have the right time sum, the fastest (or nearly) as possible ?

Comment: You mean the difference between adjacent rows?

Comment: No, like in the structure exemple, there can be multiple other action between action A and action B. It depends on the user filter. The user can ask the time difference between only 2 rows, or the sum of the time difference between action S and action T, within 300,000 rows.

Comment: But there are 4 S and 4 T rows. Which ones it supposed to compute the difference between? Please give an example of the result that should be achieved with the sample data. Also show what you've tried so far. SO is for helping you fix your code, not getting other people to write it for you.